# Looking for an If statement to check to see if a user is a local administrator

Tags: powershell

Currently very noobish with powershell but learning my way around. Looking to make a script that checks to see if the user is apart of the local admin group. Currently what I have will check if the account is created and will create it and set the password and group.

```
#add administrator account to local machine and add to administrator group

if (Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount='true' and Name='administrator'")

{
    Write-Host "Account already exists"
    Write-Host "Skipping account creation of local account administrator"

}

else

{
    Write-Host "creating Local Admin Account"
    Write-Host "Please Set the password for the Local Admin account to create it"
    $Password = Read-Host -AsSecureString
    New-LocalUser "Administrator" -Password $Password -FullName "Help Desk Administrator" -Description "Local Admin account"
    Add-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators -Member administrator
    Write-Host "account administrator created"
}
```

However I need error checking to make sure that if the account already exists that is part of the admin group.

the current state of local admins on machines here is a mess

Comment: I would recommend against the way you are approaching this. Windows has a built-in local administrator account with a sid: `S-1-5-21-domain-500`. If this account has been renamed, it would be very confusing to have another local account created named "Administrator".  I would recommend that the changes that you make to the admin account are done through Group Policy which will guarantee enforcement and consistency. All other accounts membership in the Administrators group would also be best set via Group Policy. Either Group Policy Preference (more flexible) or Required Groups.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to find out if the current user is elevated, here are two ways in PowerShell:

1. Use `#requires -RunAsAdministrator`. This will prevent your script from running if the current user is not elevated. This requires PowerShell 3.0 or later.
2. Ask the system at runtime if the current user is elevated; e.g.:

   ```
   $elevated = ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
   ```

If you are looking for a way to manage the membership of the `Administrators` group, then that is a different question. Usually I recommend Group Policy for that.